# Why are models from store already updated before model.save is called?

Tags: ember.js

I was testing some behavior in ember.js.

The scenario:

I have a simple model called `Team` with property `name`.

I am using the fixures-adapter for the team.

I implemented inline-editing in a list-view. The Textbox-fields are bound to the models property "name".

The Object-Controller handles the SaveEvent. In the SaveEvent i do following:

```
    App.TeamController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {

            save: function(){ 
                       var model = this.get('model');

                       // alerts changed text from textbox which is bound to the model
                       alert(this.get("model.name")); 

                       //load unchanged Object from store (before calling save):    
                       var fromStore = this.store.getById('team',2); 

                      // Also alerts the changed content from the text box
                      alert(fromStore.get("name")); 
                  }
            }
    });
```

Why is the alert of this.get("model.name") equals to alert(fromStore.get("name")) without calling model.save()? Between: When I use this.store.find('team',2) and resolve the thenable-result, the behavior is still the same.

How would the code behave, when I would use an own adapter against a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store only has one copy of a record.  So when you fetch it from the store again it's returning the exact same instance to you as you already have.

`save` persists the record to your server, not persists to the store.

the properties aren't set in stone in the record until you've successfully persisted.  You can still do `record.rollback()` to revert the changes that have occurred.